# JS: Check Input Box In a certain TD

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to download images from a website that require you to check the input boxes of the images you want to download. Since I want to download them all I have this JS script to check all the input boxes..

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++){
    if (allInputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
        allInputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

But the problem now is this site has two types of images, low-res and high-res and there are individual input boxes for each option per image.

Of course I want the high-res only. I've found that the high-res and low-res image input boxes are invidiually embbed in a `<tr>` tag. The high-res image input box is wrapped around a `<td align="left">` within the `<tr>` tag.

How can I tell JS to look only in `<td align="left">` tags for input boxes and check them all?

Comment: How about using Element.hasAttribute() ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute

Answer (score 1):

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++){
    if (allInputs[i].type === 'checkbox' && allInputs[i].parentNode.nodeName === 'TD' && allInputs[i].parentNode.getAttribute("align") === 'left' )
        allInputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

Comment: This actually didnt work but thats probably my fault.. I found out the high-res inputboxes have a name attribute :O so I tweaked your code up a bit and got it to work. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
var inputs = document.body.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var i = inputs.length;
while (i--) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  var parentAlign = input.parentNode.getAttribute('align');
  if (parentAlign === 'left') {
    input.checked = true;
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/pukixiniga/edit?html,js,output